# How to prevent a browser from caching videos?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, caching

I'm developing a website for school. It's a online store with a cart. One of it's requirements is to **upload, erase and display videos**, one for each product. I decided to use inputs of type video for this.

**Each product has one video**, and all the administrators can upload, erase and view videos correctly.
The problem is that when I erase one and upload another video, **the first video stays in cache** and gets displayed instead of the second one. Even if I refresh or clean the browser's cache it stays like that.

I'm absolutely sure videos are not the same (already checked), but I can tell that maybe the browser thinks they are because **their files have the same name**. I decided to store the video files according to the id of the product, because each product has only one video and that simplifies things.

**So that, when I upload a second video, it has the same name as the first one. Is that a problem? How can I prevent this from happening?**

Comment: have you experienced this with google chrome or also with other browsers?

Comment: Also with firefox

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that when i erase one and upload another video, the first video stays in cache and get's displayed instead of the second one.

You should assign a new filename when the video is replaced. Generate and store a random filename (or a MD5/SHA1 hash of the file's contents, perhaps) when a video is uploaded, rather than overwriting the same file location.

Alternatively, store the date/time the video is changed, and add that as a query string parameter on the video's URL, like `video.mp4?time=1481754713`, which the browser will see as a separate URL for caching purposes.

Comment: That could be a solution. But  why even cleaning the cache the first video continues to be displayed?

Comment: @Hernan Then something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a problem is in a server cache or who knows what (I had that problems with flash players before), but you can avoid that by simply adding ie unixtimestamp (`time()`) at the end of a name of your video - or OK, id of xy product.

For that to achieve, we need your actual php upload function which stores, copy your video files at server copy pasted here to add "rename" function as a part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a fix for this problem on a single page application. You need to dynamically change the video tag to an identical video tag and the browser will play the appropriate video.

I have done this with Svelte.

I have to use identical video tags:

[image: tags]

I toggle the `next` variable from `true` to `false` as I change to the next video:

[image: code]

Comment: Please share more details about how to resolve the problem, like any code that should be neccessary

Comment: Please provide your code as properly formatted text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

put this meta at top of page, it won't cache anything:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
```

Comment: I've been trying it out because I ran into the same problem... It works but it takes a few minutes. It's not instant, but it takes about five or ten minutes.. I'm still trying to figure out just how long. The problem I was having is that I have a movie which I update all the time. It wasn't updating immediately but it DOES happen . Just a note: this will prevent everything from being cached so every request for your page will load directly from your website.. I couldn't tell any difference in losing e times on my site. Hope this works ✌️